# Hyphen character not shown properly

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, utf-8

I am uploading a XML file for RSS feeds, fom the link, it shows all the feeds but on IE the french word is **Tobique–Mactaquac** (hyphen between two words) but where RSS is shown, it does not show hyphen and displays as **TobiqueMactaquac**. My charset is set to UTF-8
Hyphen between these two words is shown only in IE. the link to RSS is [here](http://news.gc.ca/web/rss-eng.do?mthd=dpt&crtr.dpt1D=6656)

Comment: That's not a hyphen, it's an EN DASH, `U+2013`.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a hyphen or an em or en dash?  If one o the two latter, you need to use the appropriate HTML entity reference rather than the literal. And just to be clear, this has nothing to do with French specifically, so you ought to edit your question.

Comment: Hmm. When I "View page source" on this web page, I see `<strong>Tobique–Mactaquac</strong>`, with a literal EN DASH character,  and it displays correctly (at least using Chrome on Windows 7). Does the use of RSS affect this?

Comment: Not totally sure, but it's generally a good practice for XML and HTML to use entity references for extended characters. The charset being set to UTF-8 doesn't guarantee success, particularly with literals. And the charset declaration refers to how it should be interpreted. If it isn't *emitted* as UTF-8, you won't get properly encoded double-byte chars.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved after using **iso-8859-1** charset on that specific page